# Change color in QLineEdit in Python

Tags: python, pyqt5

I changed the background color to gray and the label color to yellow, but the color of the boxes was also changed to gray and the text inside of them changed color to yellow.

I want to change the colors of the QLineEdit to white and the text inside of them to black, but I don't know how to do it

```
import sys, re
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QDialog, QFormLayout, QCheckBox, QComboBox, QSpinBox, QDialogButtonBox, QMessageBox, QErrorMessage, QToolTip, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QLabel, QTextEdit, QMainWindow, QGroupBox, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import ctypes

class Dialog(QDialog):
    NumGridRows = 10
    NumButtons = 4

    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()
        self.createFormGroupBox()
        
        self.setStyleSheet("background:rgb(66,85,99);")
        
        buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        buttonBox1 = QPushButton('Export',self)
        buttonBox1.setStyleSheet("background:rgb(255,199,44);")
        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)
        buttonBox.setStyleSheet("background:rgb(255,199,44);")
        
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.formGroupBox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(buttonBox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(buttonBox1)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        
        self.setWindowTitle("Cuadro seguimiento")

    def createFormGroupBox(self):
        self.formGroupBox = QGroupBox("New")
        self.formGroupBox.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255,199,44);")
        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Fecha"), QLineEdit())
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Dias abiertos"), QLineEdit())
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Nombre del caso"), QLineEdit())
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Responsable"), QLineEdit())
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Ok MKT"), QLineEdit())
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Solicitud Lotus"), QCheckBox())
        layout.addRow(QLabel("OS"), QLineEdit())
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Monto"), QLineEdit())
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Fecha cierre"), QLineEdit())
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Comentario"), QLineEdit())
        self.formGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = Dialog()
    sys.exit(dialog.exec_())
```

Comment: could you explain better, your explanation is confusing

Comment: Now I explained it better @eyllanesc

Comment: @Chubb Stylesheet rules cascade to child elements. You need to specify which classes to apply the rules to. So try: `self.setStyleSheet("QDialog {background:rgb(66,85,99);}")` and `self.formGroupBox.setStyleSheet("QGroupBox, QLabel {color: rgb(255,199,44);}")`.